# How can I save two different Sikuli scripts in a single folder

Tags: sikuli

Please help me out how to save the scripts in a single folder since I am facing the issue while importing Script1 inside Script2. Below are the two scripts.

Script1 : Variable.sikuli

```
PID = "r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe'"
```

When i saved the script(Variable.sikuli) , by default it will create a folder "Variable.sikuli" inside that "Variable.py" and "Variable.html"

Script2 : openMO.sikuli

```
def openMO():
    openApp(PID) # PID will taken from Variable.sikuli
openMO()
```

When I saved the script(openMO.sikuli), by default it will create a folder "openMO.sikuli" inside that "openMO.py" and "openMO.html"

Now my questions are:

1. How to save the two scripts in a single folder?
2. How to import Variable.sikuli in openMO.sikuli?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should or can place multiple Sikuli scripts into one folder to make them visible to each other. Generally, the directories/folders containing your .sikuli’s you want to import have to be in `sys.path`. Sikuli automatically finds other Sikuli scripts in the same directory, when they are imported. Your imported script must contain (as first line) the following statement:

```
from sikuli import *
```

This is necessary for the Python environment to know the Sikuli classes, methods, functions and global names.

Below is an example

```
# on Windows
myScriptPath = "c:\\someDirectory\\myLibrary"
# on Mac/Linux
myScriptPath = "/someDirectory/myLibrary"

# all systems
if not myScriptPath in sys.path: sys.path.append(myScriptPath)

# supposing there is a myLib.sikuli
import myLib

# supposing myLib.sikuli contains a function "def myFunction():"
myLib.myFunction() # makes the call
```

More info is available [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#importing-other-sikuli-scripts-reuse-code-and-images).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a late answer but if you would like to import things like a path to another file, you could also try making use of a global variable.

Putting multiple scripts inside one .sikuli folder is not advised. 
If your scripts/programs get bigger it could become real messy.

With a global variable you make a variable that can be used throughout the whole script. 
When you import a file in python it runs the class right away, and the variables are set. 
If you define a global variable in script A, and then let script B import script A. Then script B also knows how the global variables of script A look like.

To set or use a global variable in a definition you have to call it first by using: "global variableName"

I have some example code below that might make things more clear.

File: BrowserPath.sikuli

```
# Define a Global variable 
PathFireFox = ''

class Fire():
    def __init__(self):
        global PathFireFox
        PathFireFox = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

# Run Fire()
Fire()
```

File: BrowserMain.sikuli

```
# Import other class. 
from BrowserPath import *

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        global PathFireFox
        App.open(PathFireFox)

# Run Main class 
Main()
```